# Creating a More/Less "Display Box" over Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wish to create something like the image below where the lower info box overlays across the map layer and can be opened and closed. I believe I can experiment and try my hand out with the more detailed part of the developing it but I am not sure how to get started (except for thinking that maybe it'd involve some form of Fragments). If anyone can tell me what this is called and/or how to go about starting work on it, it would be of great help!

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bottom Sheets can be used to implement the design the images show.

From google material design documentation.
"A bottom sheet is a sheet of material that slides up from the bottom edge of the screen.
Bottom sheets are displayed only as a result of a user-initiated action, and can be swiped up to reveal additional content. A bottom sheet can be a temporary modal surface or a persistent structural element of an app."

Reference:-
https://materialdoc.com/components/bottom-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned libraries for your requirement,

- https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout
- https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout
- https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout